# Command netsh using C#

Tags: c#, wifi, netsh

I want to create a C# application to create a WLAN network. I currently use netsh using command prompt. My application should do this in button click. Here is the command I use in command prompt in admin mode "netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=sha key=12345678" after that I enter "netsh wlan start hostednetwork". When I do this i can create a wifi local area network. In C#  I coded like below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Process p = new Process();
     p.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
     p.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=sha key=12345678"+"netsh wlan start hostednetwork";            
     p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     p.Start();                       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't do this: `+"netsh wlan start hostednetwork"` to the arguments of the first process. That would mean that you are typing this at the console:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=sha key=12345678netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Instead, make a new process for the second line:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Process p1 = new Process();
     p1.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
     p1.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=sha key=12345678";            
     p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     p1.Start();

     Process p2 = new Process();
     p2.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
     p2.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan start hostednetwork";            
     p2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     p2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     p2.Start();
}
```